# Apache not starting - Clean install

Tags: apache

I just reinstalled Apache and now it will not start.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to start Apache :

 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Sat May 17 01:48:30 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:443 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat May 17 01:48:30 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I need to know why it won't start. If anything else is needed just ask.

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name

Comment: It says `Address already in use`, so check what process listening on port 80 with `sudo netstat -tulpn`

Comment: @masegaloeh Its ays that dovecot is but when I turn it off it still gives me this error

Comment: If after you turn it off the error is same, maybe `dovecot` didn't quit successfully. Try to `kill` it.

Comment: @masegaloeh I read the list wrong, there were actually many processes of apache running

Comment: Then restart the apache process to bring new apache binary with `apachectl restart`